# Angular child using auxilary route

Tags: angular2-routing

I have a component declared in TESTMODULE that I want to render a named auxilary route in the child component.html

The App.html has a router-outlet and I lazy load the component w/ specified module.
Do I use the definition of the route and outlet in App-Routing or my TESTMODULE-routing module?